# Laravel debugger duplicate queries

Tags: laravel

I am a newbie at Laravel and trying to figure out Laravel 4.2 and sentry 2.1. Also I am using laravel debugger by https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar . While debugging after user logs in I get a 6 queries and a message like this:
[image]
So I am not sure why is the second query duplicated, does maybe anyone has experience with this? I googled the problem but no answer.

Comment: How about the code you're using? Can you include it?

Comment: Maybe because you execute the query 6 times? Can you show us the code for this controller?

Comment: hmm, this is default made by Sentry 2.1. package

Comment: hmm interesting thing i noticed, i opened already a sample project https://github.com/rydurham/L4withSentry and the same thing is happening there

Answer (score 0):

I made a deeper search and found that was a bug in sentry 2.1 and planned to be fixed in next version, probably sentinel. https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/269